# django / filter the fields of a form and have the error 'int' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

I use `django-cities-light` for a travel website and I would like to filter the cities in the fields `ville_de_depart` and `ville_destination` in the `newBookingForm` by `trip.depart` and `trip.destination`.

I tried to pass the trip object in the instance of `newBookingForm`. I override the `__init__` and I took the value of the depart and destination, I succeeded in filtering the fields but I could no longer save the `newBooking`, the view redirect to the alltrip page with no error but no new booking is added to the database.

I tried to replace the trip by the slug which is the same value as the id and it shows me this error

```
'int' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

models.py

```
class trip(models.Model):
    depart = models.ForeignKey(default='',to=Country,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='depart') 
    destination = models.ForeignKey(default='',to=Country,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_de_depart = models.DateField(default='')
    prix_kg = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='')
    collecte = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=False,help_text='' )
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')
 
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, default='' )

    #jouter slug
    def save(self, *args , **kwargs):
        super(trip, self).save(*args , **kwargs)
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self.id
            self.save()
    

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} {self.author} '


class Booking(models.Model):
    trip = models.ForeignKey(trip,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='',)
    author =  models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ville_de_depart = models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, default='' )
    # ville_depart = models.ForeignKey(default='',to=City,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='ville_dep')
    sender_phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    receiver_phone = PhoneNumberField()    
    ville_destination = models.ForeignKey(default='',to=City,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='ville_dest')

    #jouter slug
    def save(self, *args , **kwargs):
        super(Booking, self).save(*args , **kwargs)
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self.id
            self.save()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.trip.author)
```

views.py

```
def detailsTrip(request, slug):    
    trip = get_object_or_404(models.trip,slug=slug)    
    auth = trip.author
   
    bookingForm = newBookingForm(instance=slug)
    context = {'trip': trip, 'auth': auth, 'form': bookingForm}
  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = newBookingForm(request.POST , instance=slug )

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if form.is_valid():
                trip = get_object_or_404(models.trip,slug=slug)
               
                Booking = form.save(commit=False)
                Booking.trip_id= trip.id
                Booking.author_id = request.user.id
                Booking = form.save()
                
                return redirect('/alltrips')
            else:
                trip = get_object_or_404(models.trip,slug=slug)
                auth = trip.author
                bookingForm = newBookingForm()

                context = {'trip': trip, 'auth': auth, 'form': bookingForm}
                return render(request, 'detailstrip.html', context)
        else:
            return render (request, 'notFound.html')
        
    return render(request,'detailstrip.html', context , )
```

forms.py

```
class newBookingForm(forms.ModelForm,):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        # capture the instance : Slug
        slug = kwargs.get('instance')

        # capture current trip
        Trip = get_object_or_404(trip, id=slug)
    
        # Filter cities field by the instance : trip.depart  / trip.destination
        super(newBookingForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['ville_de_depart'].queryset = City.objects.filter(country_id=Trip.depart)
        self.fields['ville_destination'].queryset = City.objects.filter(country_id=Trip.destination)
       
    class Meta:
            model = Booking
            fields = ['ville_de_depart','ville_destination']
            exclude = ['sender_phone','receiver_phone']
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use many-to-many fields, you need to call form.save_m2m() after saving the model instance. or you can just call form.save() without commit=False keyword argument.

Here are some quotes from Django documentation:

> This save() method accepts an optional commit keyword argument, which accepts either True or False. If you call save() with commit=False, then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database.

> Another side effect of using commit=False is seen when your model has a many-to-many relation with another model. If your model has a many-to-many relation and you specify commit=False when you save a form, Django cannot immediately save the form data for the many-to-many relation.

read this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) about the save method

Answer (score 0):

solution

#view.py

```
def detailsTrip(request, slug):

trip = get_object_or_404(models.trip,slug=slug)
auth = trip.author
#add the trip to the form
bookingForm = newBookingForm(trip=trip)

context = {'trip': trip, 'auth': auth, 'form': bookingForm}


if request.method == 'POST':

    #add the object trip to the form here too

    form = newBookingForm(trip,request.POST )

    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        if form.is_valid():
            trip = get_object_or_404(models.trip,slug=slug)
           
            Booking = form.save(commit=False)
            Booking.trip_id= trip.id
            Booking.author_id = request.user.id
            Booking = form.save()
            
            return redirect('/alltrips')
        else:
            trip = get_object_or_404(models.trip,slug=slug)
            auth = trip.author
            bookingForm = newBookingForm()

            context = {'trip': trip, 'auth': auth, 'form': bookingForm}

            return render(request, 'detailstrip.html', context)
    else:
        return render (request, 'notFound.html')

return render(request,'detailstrip.html', context , )
```

form.py

```
class newBookingForm(forms.ModelForm,):
class Meta:
    
        model = Booking
        fields = ['ville_de_depart','ville_destination']
        exclude = ['sender_phone','receiver_phone']

       
def __init__(self,trip,*args,**kwargs):

        
        # Filter cities field by trip.depart  / trip.destination
        super(newBookingForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['ville_de_depart'].queryset = City.objects.filter(country=trip.depart)
        self.fields['ville_destination'].queryset = City.objects.filter(country=trip.destination)
```

Comment: when you call form.save(commit=False) it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database. the commit keyword means to apply data to the database. You may use this method if you want to do custom processes on the object before saving it, as you do in your code above.